# I need to update an application to be available in French using pre-translated words stored in a .resx file at the push of a button

Tags: wpf, vb.net, xaml, resx

I am given two .resx files which provide all the words I'll need to use in English and French. Right now, the application is only available in English, and I need to create a button that will change the content of labels to point to the French .resx instead of the English one and vice-versa. The button will say English if French is the current language and Francais if English is the current.

The way the program is written currently, the language is hardcoded so that the labels only look at the English .resx, and aren't fluid depending on a selected language. I am new to this kind of programming and I'm stumped.

```
<Label Margin="12,2.222,0,0" Content="{Resx ResxName=LegalServicesTimesheets.Labels, Key=ApplicationTitleDASH}"/>

''Both .resx files have words associated with the key ApplicationTitleDash
''The French .resx file is called Labels.fr-CA.resx
```

As you can see, the English setting is currently hard-coded and I need to make it so the .resx file depends on which language is currently being used.

Comment: If you're using Visual Studio, you're not writing VBA code - more likely VB.NET.

Comment: See if [this article](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/35159/WPF-Localization-Using-RESX-Files) helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`{Resx ...}` is a markup extension. Looks like you're using the [**ResxExtension**](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/35159/WPF-Localization-Using-RESX-Files) by Grant Frisken:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Resx ResxName=MyApp.TestWindow, Key=MyText}"/>
```

You don't have anything to change in your XAML markup. If you want you can specify a `Language` attribute and bind to, say, some `UICulture` property (a `CultureInfo` object) on your ViewModel:

```
<Window ResxExtension.DefaultResxName="WpfApp.MainWindow" Language="{UICulture}">
```

But otherwise the way .resx works, it pulls from whatever resource file best matches the `Culture` of the resource object, i.e. in your case:

```
LegalServicesTimesheets.Culture = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("fr-CA")
```

If you set the culture to a culture that doesn't have a .resx file, it should fall back to the "neutral" .resx content. Since you *do* have a `.fr-CA.resx` file,  all resources pulled from `LegalServicesTimeSheets` will now be pulled from the `.fr-CA.resx` file.

In code-behind, you can retrieve resource strings ad-hoc through the `ResourceManager`, by specifying a `CultureInfo` argument to the `GeteString` method:

```
foo = LegalServicesTimesheets.ResourceManager.GetString("Labels", CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture)
```

Comment: I didn't need to use the ResourceManager, but this really helped, so thanks!